# PySide6 set position of a pop-up editor from a tableview

Tags: python, dialog, delegates, qtableview, pyside6

I got the following problem:

I have a GUI with a qtableview, a generic delegate (as in the book of Marc Summerfield) and a datamodel for that.

I designed a Dialog which shows up, if i want to change certain columns. There is a label, a combobox and a button in the dialog.

Until now, everything works fine, selection can be done, data can be processed.

But there is no possibility to set the position where the dialog pops up. So sometimes it is simply un-operatable (almost off the screen and so on)

So my question:
How can I set the position, where the dialog pops up?

Minimum example:

The generic delegate

```
class GenericDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GenericDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.delegates = {}
        
    def insertColumnDelegate(self, column, delegate, **kwargs):
        delegate.setParent(self)
        self.delegates[column] = delegate
    
    def removeColumnDelegate(self, column):
        if column in self.delegates:
            del self.delegates[column]
    
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        delegate = self.delegates.get(index.column())
        if delegate is not None:
            delegate.paint(painter, option, index)
        else:
            QItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        delegate = self.delegates.get(index.column())
        if delegate is not None:
            return delegate.createEditor(parent, option, index)
        else:
            return QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        delegate = self.delegates.get(index.column())
        if delegate is not None:
            delegate.setEditorData(editor, index)
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.setEditorData(self, editor, index)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        delegate = self.delegates.get(index.column())
        if delegate is not None:
            delegate.setModelData(editor, model, index)
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.setModelData(self, editor, model, index)
    
    def setDelegateData(self, index, data):
        delegate = self.delegates.get(index.column())
        if delegate is not None and hasattr(delegate, "setDelegateData"):
            delegate.setDelegateData(data)
        else:
            pass
```

The columns delegate

```
class ComboBoxColumnDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    
    def __init__(self, dialog, editordata=[], parent=None, target="Folder"):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.editor = dialog
        self.parent = parent
        self.editordata = editordata
        self.target = target
        
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = self.editor(parent=self.parent, target = self.target, values=self.editordata)
        return editor

    def setDelegateData(self, data = {}):
        if not data:
            return 0

        for key, value in data.items():
            if hasattr(self, key):
                setattr(self, key, value)
    
    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setData(self.editordata)
    
    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):  
        if editor.result() == QDialog.Accepted:
            model.setData(index, editor.selectedChoice(), Qt.EditRole)
```

For the dialog, a normal QDialog can be taken, since only the position of it matters.

In the mainwindow I initialize the delegate:

```
class mw(QMainWindow)

    def __init(self, parent=None):
        super(mw, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self._init_testtablemodel()
        ....

    def _init_testtablemodel(self):

        self.testmodel = testtablemodel(self)
        self.ui.tableView_tests.setModel(self.testmodel)
        #    generic delegate
        test_delegate = GenericDelegate()
        
        #    Insert the delegates for the columns
        test_delegate.insertColumnDelegate(0, ComboboxColumnDelegate())
        ...
        self.ui.tableView_tests.setItemDelegate(test_delegate)
```

The model is as recommended:

```
class testtablemodel(QAbstractTableModel)
    def __init__(self, parent=None)
        ...
    def rowCount(self, index):
        ...
    def columnCount(self, index):
        ...
    def data(self, index, role):
        ...
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        ...
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        ...
    def flags(self, index):
        ...

...
```

As mentioned befor, all data processing works perfectly nice, but the position of the editor poping up is bad.

I hope, the basic structure of the program is understandable.

**Edit:**
Changed the QItemDelegate to QStyledItemDelegate, which works as well and makes no difference so far.

Comment: Your approach of "nested" delegates is quite odd, and I'm afraid it could also be part of the issue (not mentioning that it creates an unnecessary complication to the code): for instance, the "main" delegate is a QItemDelegate, but from there you're calling base implementations of QStyledItemDelegate (and I'm actually surprised you didn't get any exception). I'd suggest you to simplify the concept with a *single* QStyledItemDelegate (or specific delegates for columns), and, most importantly, override [`updateEditorGeometry()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#updateEditorGeometry)

Comment: I followed the example from the book by Mark Summerfield (Rapid GUI prototypeing with python and qt) which gives a great flexibility on how to construct datamodels. It is for Qt4 but works on Qt5 and now on Qt6 as well. I used it several times so far, with good results and never had any problems. I will try your suggestion with updateEditorGeometry()

Comment: I sincerely doubt that that book actually suggests creating item delegates *inside* item delegates, as it wouldn't make any sense and would be just pointless. Also, as said, you should *not* mix together QStyledItemDelegate and QItemDelegate function calls; in fact, Qt docs [explicitly suggest](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#qstyleditemdelegate-vs-qitemdelegate) using the former. Besides, while conceptually will certainly be still valid, there are quite important differences between Qt4 and Qt5, and you should carefully contextualize what that book suggests, being it almost 15 years old.

Comment: Take a look for yourself: [Link](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html). It makes perfectly sense, code reusability is incredible. You never have to write another delegate, just configure one. However, the question was on how to position the dialog, not to change architecture at all. The mix of Itemdelegate and StyledItemdelegate was a typo, but both variants work. I guess, the positioning is the same, whether to use a specific delegate or a generic delegate.

Comment: That approach was valid for earlier versions of Qt4 and the author himself [explained why](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qt-interest-old/2009-March/004290.html) more than 12 years ago: at that time, Qt item views only allowed a *unique* delegate for the whole view, so a separate delegate was required for each view. That approach is clearly obsolete since Qt 4.2 (released in 2006), as you can just use [`setItemDelegateForColumn()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn) which makes things *much* more easier.

Comment: Your suggestion did not solve my problem, but is pretty usefull in the other points you described. One really important thing about this is to give every delegate for the columns a parent. Otherwise python crashes completely even without traceback. Giving the model as parent to the delegates does the trick.

Comment: Which suggestion are you referring to? Note that creating QObjects with parents is almost always a proper choice unless Qt ownership is guaranteed (which isn't the case of delegates). Depending on the object lifespan, in *some* cases that's not always required (as with item-view-like cases, like it happens with models), and most of the times it's sufficient to make them persistent, for example as instance attributes. For item delegates, it's usually better to use the view as parent, not the model: the view may change the model (which could then be destroyed, taking down the delegates with it).

Answer (score 0):

This is how finally the problem is solved:

```
def __init__(self,...):
    ...
    QTimer(0, self._resize_startup)
    ...

...

def _resize_startup(self):
    pos = QCursor.pos()
    self.move(pos)
    self.resize(QSize(350,80))
```

Simply postponing a resize/move instruction by 0 seconds moves the editor to the desired position. (The mouse cursor position in this example)

Comment: That may still be invalid, as it doesn't consider that the editor may *not* be opened by the mouse. Can you please update your original question with the newly updated code (as a comprehensive and self-contained [mre] within a single code block) including the QDialog related part?